# Composite primary key with foreign keys out to different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL 2008 R2. I have three tables.

```
**Person**
PersonID int

**Address**
AddressId int
Address varchar

**PersonAddress**
PersonID int primary key references Person.PersonID
AddressID int primary key references Address.AddressID
```

I have read that when there is a composite primary key, any reference should include both the columns. And yet, this works for me. Management studio does not throw an error and I can insert rows to these tables without any duplicates and adhering to all constraints.

Is this a good practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FK should/must reference all key columns of the *referenced* table. PersonAddress is doing that two times.